# How to add external library properly in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

So today I downloaded [Apache Commons Lang](http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang-2.5-bin.zip) library (binary, zip format). I extracted it to `C:\eclipse\commons-lang-2.5` folder. There are a `commons-lang-2.5.jar`, a `commons-lang-2.5-javadoc.jar`, and a `commons-lang-2.5-sources.jar` inside, and a folder for HTML Javadoc. I started Eclipse, added `commons-lang-2.5.jar`, and set its source and Javadoc respectively as the screenshot below. (http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9378/eclipsev.png)

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

My question is, is there a convenient or standard way to add external libraries? Or am I actually doing the right thing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Recommendation:

1. Create a "lib" folder and keep all your jars in the folder.
2. Subsequently, add all the jar files in the lib folder into your build path by using `Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add JAR ...`

btw, there' no screenshot. Can you give the link for the screen shot so that I may be able to help our better...

Comment: @MasterGaurav Should I create the 'lib' folder in my project's directory or in Eclipse's directory.

Answer (score 3):

You must add jar file on lib folder
and then right click on jar file and click "build path"-->add to build path
and now you can write that jar file code

Answer (score 2):

## Use `maven`

You **don't** have to **download all jar's** into a folder **by yourself**! -
**use maven**. It's based on a public repository, and you manage your dependencies in an xml file.

Your project will have a `pom.xml` file that going to look like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

and in this file you manage the external library dependencies

for instance, if you wish to add this dependency - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

you will need to modify your `pom.xml` like so:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

and save it. that's it

- Read this getting started tutorial - https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/
- eclipse plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As the question is quite general, maybe following detailed answer could help others:

- Right click on your project name
- Select and expand the correct (e.g C/C++) compiler
- Go to "Includes"
- On right hand corner, you would see a small icon to "add path" to include your custom library
- Add, build and happy compiling