# Adding external libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I create new projects in Eclipse regularly and every time when I add a Servlet to one of them I get the error `import javax.servlet can't be resolved`

To solve this I have to add a jar to the project.

So is there any method such that the required JARs are added to all of my projects ,i.e., I don't have to add them again and again whenever I create a new project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add external library properly in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse)

Comment: @donfuxx No the question u specified has an answer adding the libraries to a particular project only.But I'm asking to add a library for all the projects not just a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` and creating each project as a `Dynamic Web Project`.  It will ask you which container you are using (like `Apache Tomcat 7.0.x`), but it will add the necessary JARs to the classpath for you.  Anything you drop in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder will also be added automatically to the classpath.

Comment: Though I've always added the JARs to WEB-INF/lib for each and every project I've created still it isn't automatically added  to the classpath and isn't made available to the other projects.Thats why I'm all "hacked up".

Comment: Do not add `servlet-api.jar` to `WEB-INF/lib` of your projects.  Just create them as `Dynamic Web Project`s and tell it you're targeting `Apache Tomcat 7.0` (or whatever you use).