# Formula fails if variables are null

Tags: java, android

My floatpoint formulas fail to function if there is a null variable. IE if one of the input variables is null, then no result is displayed in the TextView that displays the result.

As far as I can tell there are 2 solutions to this.

One sets the null EditTexts to `0` if they are null:

```
if (charisma == null) {
        charisma.setText(0);
    } else if (charisma != null) {
        charisma.setText(getcharisma);
    }
```

The other ignores null variables in the equation:

```
try {
        float FP = Float.parseFloat(pref.getString("fp", ""));
        float CHR = Float.parseFloat(charismafpvalue.getText().toString());
        float PER = Float.parseFloat(persuasionfpvalue.getText().toString());
        float ELI = Float.parseFloat(elicitationfpvalue.getText().toString());
        float AML = Float.parseFloat(animalhandlingfpvalue.getText().toString());

        if (charismafpvalue == null) {
            fpr.setText(Float.toString(FP - (PER + ELI + AML)));    
        } else if (charismafpvalue != null) {
            fpr.setText(Float.toString(FP - (CHR + PER + ELI + AML)));
        }



    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {}
```

The problem is that my code for both of these fails to function. The values aren't set to 0 if they are null and the formula failed to function despite the `if() {} else if() {}` code.

Any suggestions as to which is the better way to handle this? And how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to solve this is to use Apache Commons [`NumberUtils#toFloat(String str, float defaultValue)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#toFloat(java.lang.String,%20float)) method:

```
float chr = NumberUtils.toFloat(charismafpvalue.getText().toString(), 0.0f);
...
```

This sets `chr` to the default value if the conversion fails, so there is no need for `try-catch` either.

Comment: this results in the following error: `NumberUtils cannot be resolved`

Comment: It seems to fail to import NumberUtils.

Comment: Yes, this is part of an external dependency provided by Apache Commons called Commons Lang. You can read more about it and download it [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Comment: I must be missing something, but I can't seem to figure out how to install it... any help here?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse) is an example on how to di it in Eclipse. There are similar questions for other IDEs as well.

Comment: I followed those instructions but when I try to add the .jar files I can't seem them in Eclipse. I've restarted Eclipse already. ~~EDIT~~ Nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Improve you're String validation.

```
if (charismafpvalue != null && ! charismafpvalue.isEmpty()) {
  // doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null cannot be casted to Float so you first need to check

```
      if(charismafpvalue !=null && charismafpvalue.getText().toString()!=null && !charismafpvalue.getText().equals(""))
```

similarly to the other views

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Float.valuOf(String s)
```

Which returns a float representation of "s" if available, or catch the NPE if "s" is null. Like so:

```
try
{
    float someFloat = Float.valueOf(someString);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{
}
catch(NullPointerException npe)
{
}
finally {}
```

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Of course, this is here for completeness really. Null checking is always a winner! And Keppil's answer is very good also :)

Hope this helps