# How do I reference an external library in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a .NET developer who decided that mono is a little too buggy and not right for my project. So I started learning Java...

One of the problems I face at the moment is not knowing how to add references to external libraries. Like how you add references to dlls in .NET.

I realise this may vary depending on the IDE... I am using Eclipse at the moment.

I also wanted to know if Java/Eclipse has a package manager like NuGet for .NET?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn JNI...

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks SSH... I wasn't sure about reference as a terminology for Java. I mean I thought that it may have a different meaning in Java than it does in .NET. That is why I didn't look at existing questions.  Thanks for confirming this for me... I will have a look at the question now.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html)!

Gradle is a lot more light weight than maven and incredibly more flexible. In fact, the configuration files are Groovy code! No verbose XML, you can add custom functions and more. I used it for a large web app and it was light years from Maven (which I had previously used extensively). It uses the Maven repositories to fetch dependencies and it works with multi-language projects in case you ever wanted to do that. Gradle is also the default build tool for Android.

Here's an example config (pasted from [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html), untested!):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

If you are using Eclipse, just add the line `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` at the top and Gradle will integrate perfectly with Eclipse by generating Eclipse project files (I haven't used Eclipse in years but I believe there are also Eclipse plugins to monitor changes to Gradle files and update Eclipse config on the fly). Gradle also has integration with IntelliJ in case you decided to switch.

Comment: Grazie Mille Giovanni, I really like the sound of Gradle however at this point I'm going to look at Maven purely because the job sites here in the UK have more contracting roles for Maven at the moment. However I will certainly be looking at Gradle next as I think that it could replace Maven in the near future.

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised anybody still uses Maven. XML config is a nightmare and it's very inflexible. Anyhow, once you understand Maven concepts it's easy to migrate a Maven project to Gradle later (I can't say the same for the opposite).

Comment: I've put Java down for a moment to focus on C++. I'm making a multi teir hobby project that will use C++ for core (for performance). I want to host a web service using Java which will report the status of the C++ application. I will take a look at both Maven and Gradle when I revisit.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `maven`

it's similar to (and for my opinion better than) NuGet.
it's based on a public repository, and you manage your references in an xml file

Each project of yours (similar to .net project) will have a `pom.xml` file that going to look like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</project>
```

And in this file you manage the references (a.k.a dependencies)

for instance, if you wish to add this dependency - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4

you will need to modify your `pom.xml` like so:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

and that's it (probably the eclipse plugin will look up for you and you will be set)

- Read this getting started tutorial - https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/
- eclipse plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin

## One more thing ...

Iv'e also moved from `.net` to `java` about 1.5 years ago, what i can honestly recommend you to use **[intellij idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)** instead of eclipse

- fully supporting maven, 0 configuration required
- best learning curve (it literally ask you from which IDE you came from and adapts the keyboard shortcuts!)
- simply awesome

Comment: Use Maven! It is a bit more work than NuGet but it is great!