# New AndroidStudio Update gives error and does not Work

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my android studio. After the update it gives me the following message (same occur when the internet is turned off):

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance(LocalFileSystem.java:41)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ApplicationStoreImpl.setPath(ApplicationStoreImpl.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10.run(ApplicationImpl.java:480)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:540)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:268)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:127)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:116)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager.getInstance(VirtualFileManager.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(LocalFileSystem.java:37)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsr166e/extra/SequenceLock
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLock.<init>(PagedFileStorage.java:489)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLock.<init>(PagedFileStorage.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.<clinit>(PagedFileStorage.java:89)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLockContext.<init>(PagedFileStorage.java:798)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:286)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.connect(FSRecords.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.connect(FSRecords.java:576)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.initComponent(PersistentFSImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:522)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jsr166e.extra.SequenceLock
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 56 more
```

Do you know how to fix it? I did update Java and restart the computer many times.

Cheers for your help!

Comment: The IDE doesnt even work at all! It is really a cumbersome issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804174/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-in-android

Comment: I figured a solution. I had to uninstall and reinstall android studio. It took a while but got it to work again!

Answer (score 0):

Plugins may make some issues after updating Android Studio to 2.3.

Just try to disable the plugins that reports any error when you are opening the Studio. Then restart the Android studio.

This worked for me. I had similar issue and I checked stack traces of studio and found that the issue was due to some error in Firebase plugin after Android Studio update. I'm not even using firebase in current project so I don't know how that makes a problem. I just disable firebase plugin and then now my device is showing in the Select Deployment Target window.