# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in Recording

Tags: java, android

I just get this error when I compile my program. I try to solve it but fail. Can someone help me on this? Thank you.

> Process: com.detection, PID: 6403
>                                                                java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.(opencv_core.java:156)
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.create(opencv_core.java:421)
>                                                                    at com.detection.MainActivity.initRecorder(MainActivity.java:188)
>                                                                    at com.detection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.sizeof(Loader.java:837)
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.(opencv_core.java:1259)
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561) 
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540) 
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.(opencv_core.java:156) 
>                                                                    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.create(opencv_core.java:421) 
>                                                                    at com.detection.MainActivity.initRecorder(MainActivity.java:188) 
>                                                                    at com.detection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90) 
>                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
>                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407) 
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>   08-17 15:52:37.291 6403-6411/com.detection E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
>   08-17 15:52:37.291 6403-6411/com.detection E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
>                                                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>                                                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
>                                                            at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.releaseWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:686)
>                                                            at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.finalize(PowerManager.java:1627)
>                                                            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:217)
>                                                            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:200)
>                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

My build.gradle is

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.detection"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
    compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
    compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.2.0-1.3'
}
```

and This is my code.

```html
package com.detection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final static String CLASS_LABEL = "RecordActivity";
    private final static String LOG_TAG = CLASS_LABEL;

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    private String ffmpeg_link = "/mnt/sdcard/stream.flv";

    long startTime = 0;
    boolean recording = false;

    private volatile FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;

    private boolean isPreviewOn = false;

    private int sampleAudioRateInHz = 44100;
    private int imageWidth = 320;
    private int imageHeight = 240;
    private int frameRate = 30;

    /* audio data getting thread */
    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private AudioRecordRunnable audioRecordRunnable;
    private Thread audioThread;
    volatile boolean runAudioThread = true;

    /* video data getting thread */
    private Camera cameraDevice;
    private CameraView cameraView;

    private opencv_core.IplImage yuvIplimage = null;

    /* layout setting */
    private final int bg_screen_bx = 232;
    private final int bg_screen_by = 128;
    private final int bg_screen_width = 700;
    private final int bg_screen_height = 500;
    private final int bg_width = 1123;
    private final int bg_height = 715;
    private final int live_width = 640;
    private final int live_height = 480;
    private int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    private Button btnRecorderControl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, CLASS_LABEL);
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        initLayout();
        initRecorder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, CLASS_LABEL);
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        recording = false;

        if (cameraView != null) {
            cameraView.stopPreview();
        }

        if(cameraDevice != null) {
            cameraDevice.stopPreview();
            cameraDevice.release();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }


    private void initLayout() {

        /* get size of screen */
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = null;
        LayoutInflater myInflate = null;
        myInflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout topLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(topLayout);
        LinearLayout preViewLayout = (LinearLayout) myInflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        topLayout.addView(preViewLayout, layoutParam);

        /* add control button: start and stop */
        btnRecorderControl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recorder_control);
        btnRecorderControl.setText("Start");
        btnRecorderControl.setOnClickListener(this);

        /* add camera view */
        int display_width_d = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_width * screenWidth / bg_width);
        int display_height_d = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_height * screenHeight / bg_height);
        int prev_rw, prev_rh;
        if (1.0 * display_width_d / display_height_d > 1.0 * live_width / live_height) {
            prev_rh = display_height_d;
            prev_rw = (int) (1.0 * display_height_d * live_width / live_height);
        } else {
            prev_rw = display_width_d;
            prev_rh = (int) (1.0 * display_width_d * live_height / live_width);
        }
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(prev_rw, prev_rh);
        layoutParam.topMargin = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_by * screenHeight / bg_height);
        layoutParam.leftMargin = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_bx * screenWidth / bg_width);

        cameraDevice = Camera.open();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cameara open");
        cameraView = new CameraView(this, cameraDevice);
        topLayout.addView(cameraView, layoutParam);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cameara preview start: OK");
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    // initialize ffmpeg_recorder
    //---------------------------------------
    private void initRecorder() {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG,"init recorder");

        if (yuvIplimage == null) {
            yuvIplimage = opencv_core.IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "create yuvIplimage");
        }

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + ffmpeg_link);
        recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
        recorder.setFormat("flv");
        recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
        // Set in the surface changed method
        recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "recorder initialize success");

        audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
        audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
        runAudioThread = true;
    }

    public void startRecording() {

        try {
            recorder.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recording = true;
            audioThread.start();

        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {

        runAudioThread = false;
        try {
            audioThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioRecordRunnable = null;
        audioThread = null;

        if (recorder != null && recording) {
            recording = false;
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (recording) {
                stopRecording();
            }

            finish();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    //---------------------------------------------
    // audio thread, gets and encodes audio data
    //---------------------------------------------
    class AudioRecordRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            // Audio
            int bufferSize;
            short[] audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioRateInHz,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleAudioRateInHz,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

            audioData = new short[bufferSize];

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            /* ffmpeg_audio encoding loop */
            while (runAudioThread) {
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording? " + recording);
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"bufferReadResult: " + bufferReadResult);
                    // If "recording" isn't true when start this thread, it never get's set according to this if statement...!!!
                    // Why?  Good question...
                    if (recording) {
                        try {
                            recorder.record(ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0, bufferReadResult));
                            //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording " + 1024*i + " to " + 1024*i+1024);
                        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"AudioThread Finished, release audioRecord");

            /* encoding finish, release recorder */
            if (audioRecord != null) {
                audioRecord.stop();
                audioRecord.release();
                audioRecord = null;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"audioRecord released");
            }
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // camera thread, gets and encodes video data
    //---------------------------------------------
    class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            Log.w("camera","camera view");
            mCamera = camera;
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(CameraView.this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(CameraView.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Setting imageWidth: " + imageWidth + " imageHeight: " + imageHeight + " frameRate: " + frameRate);
            Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview Framerate: " + camParams.getPreviewFrameRate());

            camParams.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
            mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mHolder.addCallback(null);
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // The camera has probably just been released, ignore.
            }
        }

        public void startPreview() {
            if (!isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
                isPreviewOn = true;
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }

        public void stopPreview() {
            if (isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
                isPreviewOn = false;
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            /* get video data */
            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
                yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing Frame");
                try {
                    long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                        recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                    }
                    recorder.record(yuvIplimage);
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recording) {
            startRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Start Button Pushed");
            btnRecorderControl.setText("Stop");
        } else {
            // This will trigger the audio recording loop to stop and then set isRecorderStart = false;
            stopRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Stop Button Pushed");
            btnRecorderControl.setText("Start");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804174/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Hi, if it happened in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Add **debug** in buildTypes

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
```