# How to add a non maven project jar file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project jar file. I want to add that project in eclipse. But that project is a non maven project. Is there any way to add that project in eclipse?

Comment: eclipse has import option :)

Comment: Depends on what you have inside the jar file.

Comment: Eclipse and Maven are two different tools that can work together but they are separate. The fact that proj is "not a maven project" is despitable.

Comment: Duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Just import your project in to eclipse and convert it to maven project.

```
file -> import -> existing project
```

then convert your project to maven

[image]