# How to install java library in eclipse on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse

I feel stupid for asking this question but I can't find any info on how to get this done and I've never installed a Java library before.

I'm using Eclipse for Java programming and I want to install this library: https://github.com/SurpSG/Kombi . The instructions only mention Maven and Gradle. How can I install this library in my Eclipse project?

I'm on MacOS.

Comment: You don't "install" libraries. You need download them. They come in the form of .jar-files. You download the jar-files you need and include them to the libraries your project needs. How do you know which jars you need? Well... this is why we normally use maven or gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to add external library properly in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse#2824531) | Additional graphical tutorial found [here](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44)

Comment: Eclipse supports Maven projects, hence you just have to convert your project to Maven and then follow the guide for Maven you have. Or you download the library and it's dependencies manually from https://mvnrepository.com and add them to your project.