# Importing jar files in zip format

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I just want to know why we can't add jar files in zip format in eclipse.I tried to add external jar files as zip just to know weather it is correct or not. But it gives error.But when I google it some articles say we can add in zip format.Can anyone explain me this.

Comment: And what error might that be? Usually they are for a reason and explain things, not just “error”

Comment: It gives error as "The import org.springframework cannot be resolved"

Comment: What zip are you trying to add? Can you send a link to some online resource? When something is packaged as a zip, it's probably not meant to be added as a library in the usual way.

Comment: a .jar file IS a .zip file. are you asking if you can add a zip with jars, or compiled java classes in a zip? or javadocs in a zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text file with a `.java` extension is a Java Source File, but it *is* just a text file, so why does it have to have the `.java` extension? Because a text file with any other extension is not considered by most tools to be a Java Source File.

A zip file with a `.jar` extension is a Java Archive File, containing compiled Java Class Files (and more), but it *is* just a zip file, so why does it have to have the `.jar` extension? Because a zip file with any other extension is not considered by most tools to be a Java Archive File.

File extension matters for the determination of the file type.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research and found this:

[How to add external library properly in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse)

I then followed the steps:

1. Extracted all google api content to one folder named lib.
2. Created a New User Librarby Window -> Preference -> Java -> Build Path -> New
       -> Name your library -> left the System Library unchecked -> Add External Jars -> manually added the needed jars.
3. Right click on project folder -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
   -> Libraries ->
       Add Library -> User Library -> checked the created user library.

In conclusion: Don't ever import the library as a zip or you will have a long headache.

Hope this helps someone else.

In case of some error showing up, like missing files belonging to the user library, cleaning the project may prove to be a solution. However, refreshing the project worked just fine for me. Try pressing F5 or right clicking on your project folder and select refresh.