# Can't Create an excel file (Java)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a file in Java. I have downloaded the lastest Apache POI version and kinda having troubles with all the "build path" thing. I'm not sure if I was doing everything right and not sure what jar files i should use.
I try to run the code and thats the error I get:

Error: Unable to initialize main class TestCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("Test.xlsx");
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SheetTest");
    Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
    }
    workbook.close();
}
}
```

Maybe I have a problem with the classpath? How can I change it?
If that's not the problem, Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: what IDE you using?

Comment: @PeterŠály I'm using eclipse

Comment: If you don't use maven see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: @PeterŠály I think i did add the jars correctly, its just that i have lots of jar files and im not sure which one to add.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois I didn't really understand what i need to do..

Answer (score 0):

firstly be sure that you are using the latest version  of this library 
in case  you are using maven these dependencies helping you

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

also you have to create a file with .xls or .xlsx extensions
 you can use something like this

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));

Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheetName");
int rowIndex = 0;
// this is an example from the official site  iterate over the list  and fill the  sheet 
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    Country country = iterator.next();
                    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
                    Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
                    cell0.setCellValue(country.getName());
                    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
                    cell1.setCellValue(country.getShortCode());
                }
//lets write the excel data to file now
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println(fileName + " written successfully");
```

Comment: Those versions are ancient! They are [over 5 years old, with loads of bugs found and fixed](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.10-FINAL)! Why on earth are you suggesting people use old versions?

Comment: Also, why are you doing the format detection by hand? Why not use `WorkbookFactory` instead?

Comment: See [the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) - the `poi` and `poi-ooxml` jar versions need to match. You also need to update to use `WorkbookFactory` to detect the file type

Comment: @Gagravarr those jar files are the same version, what can i do?

Comment: @HazemMusallam what is this maven for? I don't know what is it. how can i use the apache poi I have downloaded? I have the last version of this API

Comment: Maven is like un organizer to your jars read about maven is worthy

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you forgot to add some jar files in the classpath. Try to follow these steps:

1. Right-click on your Project name in Package Explorer tab -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

[image: Step 1]

2. In "Libraries" tab, remove your old POI library
3. Click on "Add Library" -> User Library -> User Libraries

[image: Step 3]

4. Remove your old libraries and click on "New". Then insert the name of the library and press "ok".
5. Select your new library and click on "Add External Jars".

[image: Another step]

6. Browse to your extracted POI path and select **all the jar files, also in the subfolders!**
7. Now click on Apply and close and select the new library on the previous window.

Now it should work!