# How to add a .zip library to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, controlsfx

I need to add an external library named ControlFX in my project. Here is the official link to download it: https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx

The issue is that this file is `.zip` type. So, I'm really confused about how can I add it as a library to my project (it doesn't include.jar files inside).

Any idea, please?

Comment: Have you reviewed: https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Building-ControlsFX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [How to add external library properly in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse) if you want to add it manually, but it's very much not advised if you don't know what you're doing.

If you want to learn the proper way to use external resources look into how to use [Maven](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html) or [Gradle](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) to incorporate libraries into your projects.